# For what A, If $A+A^T>0$ then $A^2+A^{2T}>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

let me know if I am wrong with the next with a real square matrix A.

$A+A^T = \sqrt{A^2+A^{2T}+AA^T+A^TA} > 0$

This square root exists right? And because of this, the sum of all its elements are also a positive definite matrix.

So, because $AA^T > 0$, then $-(A^2+A^{2T}) < AA^T+A^TA$, so the left hand could be negative.

Is there any way for checking the expression of the question only looking at A without computing the squares?

UPDATE

With > 0 I mean a positive definite matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by $A>0$ for a matrix $A$? Is this an entry-wise inequality ($\forall i,j \ \ A_{ij}>0$) or that it is positive-definite?

Comment: $-I+ (-I)^T = -2I$, but this is not equal to $2I$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The statement $A + A^{T}$ strictly positive implies $A^2 + A^{2T}$ strictly positive is false. Counter example: $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\-2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$. Can you clarify what you really want?

Comment: Yes sorry. Here > 0 standa for positive definite matrix. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I just want to point out that it's fairly common to denote positive definite matrices by $A>0$ or $A\succ0$ in optimization texts.

Comment: @noether, I deleted my answer because my claim on the estimation of smallest eigenvalue of $\mathscr{S}$ is simply wrong and I cannot find any simple criterion to replace that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: oh I see, anyway, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If by
$$A+A^T = \sqrt{A^2+A^{2T}+AA^T+A^TA}$$
you mean that the square of $A+A^T$ is $A^2+A^{2T}+AA^T+A^TA$ then yes, that square root does exist.

As for the question in the title we never compare matrices with numbers so $A + A^T > 0$ doesn't mean anything.  From your question I get the impression that you mean to say that the entries of the matrix $A + A^T$ are all positive numbers.  In that case it's not in general true that $A^2 + A^{2T}$ has positive entries when $A + A^T$ does.  For example take
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then you'll find that
$$A + A^T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$
has all positive entries but
$$A^2 + A^{2T} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 8 \\ 8 & 14 \end{bmatrix}$$
does not.  I suspect you'll just need to compute the squares to know if any particular $A$ gives a matrix $A^2 + A^{2T}$ with all positive entries.

Edit: If you mean does $A + A^T$ positive definite imply $A^2 + A^{2T}$ is then that is false as well.  Take
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then $A + A^T$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $3$ so it is positive definite, but $A^2 + A^{2T}$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, so it is not.

Comment: Sorry. I have forgotten to note than > 0 stands for positive definite matrix.

Comment: The statement isn't true for positive definite matrices either, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. Even semi definite is fine for my requirements. But I guess there are counter examples for that case as well.